# Why can WinDBG break on nt!NtCreateFile but not nt!NtAccessCheck or nt!SeAccessCheckByType?

Tags: windows, kernel, windbg

I'm trying to examine the token and security descriptor in an access check.  For learning purposes I wrote the following program that I could use to test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int wmain( int argc, wchar_t *argv[], wchar_t *envp[] )
{
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: OpenWithAccess <file> <read/write> [ -d ]" << std::endl;
        return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }

    if (argc == 4 && !_wcsicmp(argv[3], L"-d"))
    {
        __debugbreak();
    }

    HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFile(argv[1], !_wcsicmp(argv[2], L"write") ? FILE_ALL_ACCESS : GENERIC_READ, 0, nullptr, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::wcout << L"Successfully opened " << argv[1] << L" with " << argv[2] << L" access" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::wcout << L"Failed to open " << argv[1] << L" with " << argv[2] << L" access, error = " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    
    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I run this program with `OpenWithAccess.exe c:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts write -d` as a standard user, I know the call passes through NtAccessCheck (which fails with an access denied).

In the kernel debugger I can set a breakpoint in nt!NtCreateFile like so:

```
bp /p <myprocessaddress> nt!NtCreateFile
```

This breaks fine.  However:

```
bp /p <myprocessaddress> nt!NtAccessCheck
```

Does not break.  However, if I break in `nt!NtCreateFile` and then simply keep running `t` to trace through the API I do eventually end up in `nt!NtAccessCheck`.  So why does one breakpoint work but not the other?

I should note that if I run this without my current process like:

```
bp nt!NtAccessCheck
```

It does break, but not on my current thread, that is skipped even though I know it ran and some other access check is caught.  The one I expect is never caught.  What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you do `bu nt!NtAccessCheck ".if (@$proc != <yourproc>) { gc; }"`? Disregard performance for the purpose of this exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting a breakpoint on  **nt!SeAccessCheck** and check if it provides you enough information

i just compiled the code and wrung it through it hits nt!SeAccessCheck

```
0: kd> !process @$proc 3f
PROCESS ffffd10fc1503080
    SessionId: 1  Cid: 17b8    Peb: 55e8cf000  ParentCid: 0bd4
    DirBase: 0ef40002  ObjectTable: ffffaa883bdb1240  HandleCount:  32.
    Image: fufu.exe
```

hit bp3

```
0: kd> bp /p ffffd10fc1503080 nt!NtCreateFile
0: kd> bp /p ffffd10fc1503080 nt!IopCreateFile
0: kd> bp /p ffffd10fc1503080 nt!NtAccessCheck
0: kd> bp /p ffffd10fc1503080 nt!SeAccessCheck
0: kd> g
Breakpoint 0 hit
nt!NtCreateFile:
fffff802`4c8974e0 4881ec88000000  sub     rsp,88h
1: kd> g
Breakpoint 1 hit
nt!IopCreateFile:
fffff802`4c897570 4c894c2420      mov     qword ptr [rsp+20h],r9
1: kd> g
Breakpoint 3 hit
nt!SeAccessCheck:
fffff802`4c3bd730 48895c2410      mov     qword ptr [rsp+10h],rbx
1: kd> kb
 # RetAddr            Call Site
00 fffff802`4c942c28  nt!SeAccessCheck
01 fffff802`4c9417bf  nt!ObpLookupObjectName+0x188
02 fffff802`4c897974  nt!ObOpenObjectByNameEx+0x1df
03 fffff802`4c897559  nt!IopCreateFile+0x404
04 fffff802`4c46d785  nt!NtCreateFile+0x79
05 00007fff`2c6e0114  nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
06 00007fff`295ee5d6  ntdll!NtCreateFile+0x14
07 00007fff`295ee2c6  KERNELBASE!CreateFileInternal+0x2f6
08 00007ff7`afaa12ed  KERNELBASE!CreateFileW+0x66
09 ffffffff`fffffffe  fufu!wmain+0xed [c:\users\xxx\desktop\fufu\fufu.cpp @ 17] 
0a 00007ff7`00000002  0xffffffff`fffffffe
0b 00007ff7`afb39358  0x00007ff7`00000002
0c 00007ff7`afaa1032  fufu!std::classic_locale$initializer$
0d 00007ff7`00000004  fufu!`dynamic initializer for 'std::numpunct<wchar_t>::id''+0x12 
0e 00000000`00000080  0x00007ff7`00000004
0f 00000000`00000000  0x80
1: kd> dt nt!_SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR @rcx
   +0x000 Revision         : 0x1 ''
   +0x001 Sbz1             : 0 ''
   +0x002 Control          : 0x10
   +0x008 Owner            : 0xffffd10f`bb148fb0 Void
   +0x010 Group            : 0xffffd10f`bb148fb0 Void
   +0x018 Sacl             : 0xffffaa88`36e05c10 _ACL
   +0x020 Dacl             : (null)
```

Comment: May I ask what OS that is?  I'd tried to break on `nt!SeAccessCheck` originally since it's what I expected but it hadn't worked.  I've just disassembled `nt!ObpLookupObjectName` on my Win10 and it doesn't actually call `SeAccessCheck`, it rather calls `SeAccessCheckWithHint` instead which seems to be an undocumented variation.  Thankfully I can break on that and it seems to have very similar parameters which does give me the SD and token.  Thanks for giving it a whirl though, very interesting that it's different on your system.

Comment: it was on an outdated vm with w10 enterprise evaluation version there is no surprise all these security apis change every third day or maybe even everyday  if your machine said please do not shut off it means some security by somescurity has been implemented